# Intersecting zebra striping with darker shading at intersections?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Is there any way to achieve this in Excel:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/O7pDht1.png]

where intersecting zebra striping shades it darker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fill the whole range with this formula

   `=MOD(INT((ROW()+2)/3),2)+MOD(INT((COLUMN()-1)/2),2)`
2. Select whole range. Select in Ribbon 'Start'->Conditional Formatting->Color Scales. Use customized styles->3-color styles and select appropriate colors for minimum, middle and maximum value for the values 0,1,2 in the cells.
3. Select whole range. Select 'normal' cell formatting and apply user defined formatting with format string `;;;` to make the helper numbers in the cells invisible

Comment: It's a easy way to get the pattern. But it has got the problem that you can't use the cells anymore for 'real' values. There was nothing about this requirement in the question but I'am afraid it will be a problem :-)

Comment: Yeah, we decided to scrap the horizontal lines altogether because none of our forms are standardized in both column or rows— we have some data sets that are 3-8 rows or columns wide. But this is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could use three conditional formats (one for each shade), or two conditional formats (one each for two of the shades), and apply the third shade statically.

Comment: Hey, T! Didn't see you in any of the summit pics -- did you spend all your time behind the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

A standard fill applied to B4:S18 - the colour you want for B4 etc (the lightest shade) - and three conditional formatting formula rules (the order is not important) each with Applies to range of `=$B$4:$S$18`:

1.`=AND(MOD(COLUMN()+2,4)>1,MOD(ROW()+2,6)>2)` - for the darkest shade.
2.`=MOD(ROW()+2,6)>2`
3.`=MOD(COLUMN()+2,4)>1`

both of the latter two for the intermediate shade.